# Is software compiled with the standard minGW compatible with 32 bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, mingw

I have a very quick question.
Is software compiled with minGW (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) compatible with 32-bit? It mentions on the SourceForge page it says it runs on 64-bit. On the blog it says it runs on both. Then there is also mingw-w64, for both 32 and 64 bit. I am confused.

Thanks.

Comment: mingw-w64 is a x64 port of the x86 minGW code

Answer (score 0):

There are two "versions" of MinGW 32-bit and 64-bit. In fact, you can install both of them and compile 32-bit or 64-bit version by setting environment variable (if you have such setup). And of course if you want to compile 64-bit version, you need 64-bit systems. To setup both 32-bit and 64-bit system, I strongly recommended you follow the instructions [HERE](http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html) it works like a charm.